# MVC4 & SignalR Only executing in other windows

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, signalr, signalr-hub

I am doing an MVC4 web application and decided using signalr, there is just one thing I don't understand, I'm probably doing something wrong...

I have a page (Home) with an ActionLink that call the HomeController.
In the controller I have this:

**HomeController:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IHubContext context;
    public HomeController()
    {
        context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<HomeHub>();
    }

    ...

    public ActionResult Scan()
    {
        context.Clients.All.StartedScanning();
    }
}
```

**HomeHub:**

```
public class HomeHub : Hub
{
    public void StartedScanning()
    {
        Clients.All.setStatusMessage("Scanning started...");
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
...

@Html.ActionLink("Scan for media", "scan", null, new
{
    @class = "scanActionLink"
})

...

@section scripts
{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.1.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var home = $.connection.homeHub;

            home.client.setStatusMessage = function (message) {
                alert(message);
            }

            // Start the connection.
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            });
        })
    </script>
}
```

Actually the code is executing all right, but only in other windows and not on the main. Is that normal?

I hope I've been clear enough.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By clicking your ActionLink, you are reloading the page.  SignalR is not yet (re)loaded in the context of the new page, so the notification will not be sent to it by the server.  You may want to try the StartedScanning request as an AJAX request rather than navigating away from the current page.

Comment: It's what I was doing first, doing a Server.StartedScanning but if I do that I'm loosing all the view controller benefits right?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to achieve, but technologies like SignalR make use of long-lived connections and work best in applications that don't do too many page transitions.  Every time you navigate away from the page, you are tearing down the SignalR connection and are going to miss any notifications that happen between then and when your hub connection is re-initialized.

Comment: It was maybe a mistake in my case then to explore signalR with this application. What I'm trying to do is analyze a of contents on my HD and refreshing the page while this is happening. SignalR seems really nice, too bad I can't use all the MVC and SignalR benefits.
Thanks for your input.

Edit: Or I could still use SignalR only for long processes...

Comment: It's a tradeoff.  You need to figure out whether the "real-time push" feature is of more benefit than you are gaining by letting MVC do the work for you.  You could also consider using MVC to do a RenderPartial (via AJAX) and then using jQuery to replace *part* of your UI with what is returned by MVC, without tearing down the entire page and its SignalR connections

Comment: Ok, I'm just starting with MVC and SignalR, I will consider your advice and continue searching how to use intelligently both.

Thanks!

Comment: Would you say doing a new Task(() => myLongCode).Start(); and returning the view just after that would be a bad idea? Because actually it is working.

Comment: Tasks are an easy way to implement something like that.  If you are not worried about scale (many people doing this at once) and reliability (what if the server machine crashes in the middle) it will be fine.